# iPhone notify_post notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications

How can I find out what notifications the iPhone has registered?

for instance:

```
notify_post("com.apple.springboard/Prefs");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although an answer has already been confirmed for this question, since @Nate seemed confused about it, I thought I'd show an easier method. 
`notificationWatcher` from Erica Utilities can be used to print a list of standard notifications as they happen. Run it from the command line like so:

```
notificationWatcher -st | grep -v rawOrientation
```

You don't need the grep bit, but it's useful to remove the many `com.apple.springboard.rawOrientation` notifications that appear when the device is moving around a lot.